# Como capturar conteúdo de span por JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, whatsapp

No WhatsApp Web, cada mensagem enviada é armazenada em um **span**. Preciso atribuir o valor da última mensagem enviada pelo interlocutor a uma variável, assim como faço com o conteúdo da caixa "Envie uma mensagem":

```
var textbox = document.querySelector('#main > footer > div.block-compose > div.input-container > div.pluggable-input.pluggable-input-compose > div.pluggable-input-body.copyable-text.selectable-text');
alert(textbox.textContent);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagino que eu preciso pegar o conteúdo da última span de cor branca (linha azul, na imagem acima), mas não estou conseguindo.

Tentei da seguinte forma, mas o retorno é **null**:

```
var ultima = document.querySelector('#main > div.pane-body.pane-chat-tile-container > div.copyable-area > div.pane-chat-msgs.pane-chat-body.lastTabIndex > div._9tCEa > div.msg.msg-group > div.message.message-chat.message-in.tail.message-chat > div.bubble.bubble-text.has-author.copyable-text > div._3zb-j.ZhF0n > span.emojitext.selectable-text.invisible-space.copyable-text');
alert(ultima);
```

Estou executando o script no Console mesmo, quando clico F12 no WhatsApp Web.

Comment: Seria melhor vc postar na pergunta o código HTML da span. Há muitas formas de capturar isso, mas é preciso saber o que tem nessa span.

Comment: Pronto. Conforme a imagem, preciso capturar o conteúdo daquela linha em azul (sempre a última mensagem do WhatsApp naquela conversa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você consegue com o seguinte seletor:

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.message-in span.copyable-text'); // seleciono todas
var conta = els.length; // conto a quantidade
var texto = els[conta-1].textContent; // pego o texto da última
```

A classe `.message-in` se refere às mensagens recebidas. Neste caso, basta contar quantas existem e pegar o texto da última, diminuindo a quantidade por 1 (o `index` da coleção começa com 0, portanto, o `index` do último elemento sempre é a quantidade menos 1).

### Testar no Whatsapp Web

Se quiser testar na página do WA Web, abra o console (F12) numa conversa e execute a linha abaixo:

```
els=document.querySelectorAll('.message-in span.copyable-text');conta=els.length;texto=els[conta-1].textContent;
```

Comment: Aparece a seguinte mensagem: "VM64:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:3:26"

Comment: Aconteceu o mesmo erro... VM66:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:1:101

Comment: @lucaswmolin Aqui funcionou. Tem conversa na janela?

Comment: Opa, dei F5 e tentei de novo. Funcionou, sim. Obrigado.